# Python: Locate the max value of a column and pick up the value of other column in the same row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have next data frame with two columns:

```
Idx =[1,2,3,4,5]
Values =[7,-2,-1,10,5]
lists = list(zip(Idx, Values))  
dfsr = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns = ['Idx', 'Values'])
dfsr
```

This generates the next DataFrame

```
    Idx Values
0   1   7
1   2   -2
2   3   -1
3   4   10
4   5   5
```

What I want to do is to locate the max value in the column "values" and select the corresponding value of the column "Idx".

I have tried this:

```
MVI = dfsr[dfsr.Values == dfsr.Values.max()]
MVI
```

which leads to:

```
   Idx  Values
3   4   10
```

But what I need is just the value of the Idx. The return should be just 4 as a number to use it later.

Can somebody help me with this easy thing please? Thank you very much!

Comment: `dfsr.loc[dfsr.Values.idxmax(), 'Idx']` if you one just the first value, or `dfsr.loc[dfsr.Values == dfsr.Values.max(), 'Idx']` if you want them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
>>> MVI = dfsr.loc[dfsr.Values == dfsr.Values.max(), 'Idx']
>>> MVI
3    4
Name: Idx, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, if you just want the object itself (not `pandas.Series` object):

```py
>>> MVI = dfsr.loc[dfsr.Values == dfsr.Values.max(), 'Idx'].to_list()[0]
>>> MVI
4
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: You shouldn't use chained indexing.  Use `loc`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to ```loc```